# Using Linq 2 EF, how would I find a guid starting with 'x'?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

Using Linq2Entities (EF4), I need to query an entity that has a `Guid` property (call it `id`).  I need to query whether or not my entity has any records that have `id`s starting with a given prefix.

In essence, I need something like

```
from items in myEntity 
where items.id.ToString().StartsWith(prefix)
// rest of the query
```

Now, I know that L2EF doesn't support conversions of `Guid` members using `ToString()`.

The `SqlFunctions.StringConvert()` helper doesn't support it either as it doesn't accept a `Guid` argument.

And I can't use SQL's `LIKE`, as in

```
from items in myEntity 
where items.id like 'prefix%'
```

because it's also not supported by L2EF.

All of the recommendations I've found so far suggest using `Contains()`, but that's simply not the same as `starts with`.... In the case of `Guid`s, for example, the first 8 chars might be found in the last 13 characters.

So, how would YOU use L2EF to query records that have a Guid starting with "prefix" ?

I can think of some hacks like converting the `uniqueidentifier` field on the back end SQL database to a `varchar()`, but I'd really like to understand if I'm just doing it wrong before resorting to something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ExecuteStoreQuery` on your context and execute a custom SQL statement directly against your context.  Something like:

```
string prefix = '00000000';       
const string sql = "select * from myEntities where id like @prefix + '%'"; 
var matches = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyEntityType>(sql, prefix);
```

Also, check out this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx).

Comment: Update: After seeing that another answer was receiving more up-votes, I thought about it for a bit more.  I flagged this as the correct answer because I used it, and it absolutely works, and it is general enough to solve a larger class of potential limitations with L2EF.  But I realize now that it skirted the actual question by not using LINQ at all.  The suggestion to decouple the EF property from the database by making a string property based on the guid does indeed let you use LINQ to do the .StartsWith() query.

Answer (score 4):

Two options: 
1) change your entity data model so that whatever "x" signifies, it is moved to a property on that entity instead of tightly coupled to the unique id

2) get the whole list of entities into a collection, then after they are loaded into memory, go through and do a id.ToString().Contains() query on the collection. Once it has been loaded into memory the CLR will allow this. Though, horrible overhead.

I'd go with #1 if possible.